# Does react-bootstrap have templates like material ui

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I am new to react started using templates from material ui. I had to switch to react-bootstrap.

I wanted to know whether react-bootstrap have readymade templates like material-ui?? If so where can we find them??

Something like this: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/

Comment: I assume you mean this? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts. Also keep in mind this type of question should not be asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: No I mean something like this https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/

Comment: React is just a another layer on top of bootstrap. If you want templates, you should look for bootstrap templates, not react-bootstrap templates

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. React bootstrap have templates like material UI.
Refer below URLs for documentation in react bootstrap templates.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/
Dropdown component: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Something like this: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/

Comment: I think the question is referring to templates like: admin dashboard, blog, homepage, etc. But, this is not clear in the question, anyway...